# How to delete Greenland from my d3 visual

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this adapted d3 geography visual:

https://plnkr.co/edit/BnCRYzCH3TGEP5ypTGGu?p=preview

I would like to delete Greenland from the map and thought that commenting out the following in the `foobar.json` file would suffice:

```
            // , { "type": "MultiPolygon", "id": 86, "arcs": [
            //    [
            //        [503]
            //    ],
            //    [
            //        [504]
            //    ],
            //    [
            //        [505]
            //    ],
            //    [
            //        [506]
            //    ],
            //    [
            //        [507]
            //    ],
            //    [
            //        [508]
            //    ],
            //    [
            //        [509]
            //    ],
            //    [
            //        [510]
            //    ],
            //    [
            //        [511]
            //    ]
            // ], 
            // "properties": { "admin": "Greenland", "id": "GRL" } }
```

This adjustment breaks the complete visual - how do I delete Greenland?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier:

```
svg.select("#code_GRL").remove();
```

Here is your updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/yPgYLSSvtyDh6rW5vPyS?p=preview

Comment: PS: I'm not sure (because I'm on my mobile, which makes Plunker terrible to read), but it seems to me that you commented out *Greece*, not Greenland.

Comment: I think it was Greenland - but commenting out the json didn't get rid of either country which I find mysterious - what is the purpose of this file?

Comment: hmmm but that line with "properties" goes like this `"properties": { "admin": "Greenland", "id": "GRL" } }...` with 2 curly braces at the end so I assumed that would be the end of the Greenland info?

Comment: As I told you, I was not sure, it's really difficult using plunkr in a mobile. Now, on my laptop, I can see that you're right.

Comment: ok - Gerardo - it is as Elias mentioned - commenting out isn't possible in json but once the respective lines are deleted from the json file we can change the World!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot comment out lines in json. Removing the very same lines completely does the job though.

Comment: thanks Elias - we all learn something new everyday - this was mine